# rake task says "define INLINEDIR or HOME in your environment and try again, how do i fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, environment-variables, init.d

I am running a rake task in rails 2
I have it called from an `/etc/init.d/` ruby script.

at start up it tells me 
`define INLINEDIR or HOME  in your environment and try again`
It works fine once I Log in, but not if I run `unset home` first

it doesn't matter what task I try to call it says that no matter what.

While I could define `HOME` in that file, I don't know what `INLINEDIR` is and if I should do that instead, or why this matters in the first place..
Has anyone encountered this problem, know more about it and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to add a `ENV["HOME"] = '/root'` line into the calling script and it worked fine

very odd, found no reason what caused this or anything